# Not able to list particular bucket from IAM user account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

This is the code I wrote for s3bucket

I'm not able to list/see bucket `sseth-learning-account1` from IAM user `sseth1` S3 dashboard in AWS console although by bucket policy saved successfully without giving me any error. How can I give permission to IAM user to list/see only single bucket required for his task?

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1644033771978",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1644033769613",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::196172918120:user/sseth1"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sseth-learning-account1",
                "arn:aws:s3:::sseth-learning-account1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What command are you trying and what is the error message?

Comment: I have configured above policy at my bucket to allow IAM user to list specific bucket and perform few task on that bucket but when I'm trying to list bucket from IAM user console it gives me the error - You don't have permission to list buckets. ** But if I remove ListBucket action from policy and instead applu it to group as a role and add user to that role I'm able to list the bucket and perform all the actions define in bucket policy but how to achieve same only from bucket policy?

Comment: Are you saying that you want this user to be able to access an Amazon S3 bucket in the S3 management console, but you do not want them to see the list of other S3 buckets in that AWS Account?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes

Comment: @JohnRotenstein also from above policy if I ignore the ListBucket part for console view then I'm able to perform all the actions through cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are wanting to give a specific user permissions for Amazon S3.

The recommended way to do this is to **add a policy to the IAM User** (rather than using a Bucket Policy).

It would be the same policy you have created, but there is no `Principal` because that is implied by the IAM User that has the policy.

(This is not necessarily the cause of your problem, but you have not provided enough information to diagnose your specific issue. I'm simply explaining an alternate way to achieve your goals.)

Comment: So I am able to achieve this by doing the following:-1)Creater group and allowing that group ListAllMyBucket access only via policy 2)Adding my user to that group 3)Removing ListBucket action from bucket policy 4)I'm able to List Bucket through group and perform action through Bucket Policy
Is it the correct way and the same way you are guiding?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your goal is to allow a particular user to access an Amazon S3 Bucket via the S3 management console ***without* allowing them to see the list of other buckets**.

This is not possible.

However, you can 'cheat'...

YOU (with full permissions) should go to the bucket in the S3 management console and access the desired bucket. Then, **copy the URL from the browser** and provide this URL to the other user. They can then use that URL to directly access that bucket in the S3 management console without going via the list of buckets. This way, **they will be able to view and use that specific the bucket** in the console.

Comment: Thank you for making me understand